# React Native validate function not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to ensure I am testing this correctly.

This is what is happening:

### Test steps

1. Nav to My Account>Home Information>Home Phone
2. Input the following string: 1112345678
3. Attempt to Save and observe the error message from `validatesPhones`.
4. Change it to a correct number.
5. Attempt to save and observe the error message from `_handleSubmit` helper.

You can't input a correct number until you log out and log back in.

I believe the issue is in this `_validate` function:

```
_validate = () => {
    const isValid = Object.keys(this.props.validationErrors).reduce(
      (acc, curr) => {
        if (this.props.validationErrors[acc] !== "") {
          return false;
        }

        return acc;
      },
      true
    );

    return isValid;
  };
```

Is returning a validation of `true` when I put in the wrong type of digits, but the amount of digits is correct, so it returns `true`
and then it runs this function to tell the user the phone number has to be valid and 10 digits:

```
function validatePhones(state, payload) {
  const [key] = Object.keys(payload);
  console.log([key]);
  if (["homePhone", "mobilePhone"].includes(key)) {
    const isValid =
      payload[key].length === 0 || regex.phoneNumber.test(payload[key]);
    console.log(isValid);
    const message = isValid
      ? ""
      : "Phone number must be valid and contain 10 digits";
    console.log(message);

    return {
      ...state,
      validationErrors: {
        ...state.validationErrors,
        [key]: message
      }
    };
  }



return state;
}
```

when I enter the correct phone number after removing the incorrect phone number, the first function, the `_validate()` function `returns false`
which then `_handleSubmit` sees that and instead of submitting the phone number  it provides the alert at the end:

```
_handleSubmit = () => {
    const isValid = this._validate();
    console.log("is the phone number valid: ", isValid);
    if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ displaySpinner: true });
      this.props
        .submitPhoneNumbers(this.props)
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ displaySpinner: false });
          //eslint-disable-next-line
          this.props.navigation.goBack();
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ displaySpinner: false });
        });
    } else {
      alert("Please, fix all the errors before saving your changes.");
    }
  };
```

Is there a better way to develop that `_validate` function?

Comment: Have you set the `homePhoneChanged` prop on the `PhoneNumbersForm` component?

Comment: What do you want to send from handleSubmit in TouchableOpacity?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal, I want it to send and save the correct phone number, even after the wrong phone number has been submitted. So it does not allow me to save the correct phone number directly after I have provided a wrong one. It still prompts me to fix the phone number even though I erased the wrong one and provided the correct one.

Comment: I meant what variable/value name used in your code.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal, I have edited the question further, I believe the problem is in the `_validate` function.

Comment: @Daniel when this `validatePhones` gets triggered?? please provide code snippet of that.

Comment: @AnkitMakwana, whenever I change the digits on the phone number input element, `validatePhones` is triggered. So for each digit I remove or add, this line runs `const isValid =
      payload[key].length === 0 || regex.phoneNumber.test(payload[key]);`

Comment: @AnkitMakwana, so `validatePhones` runs as soon as you remove and add digits in the phone input field. This line will run `const [key] = Object.keys(payload);` which in this case will output `"homePhone"` like so: `["homePhone"]
0: "homePhone"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`. And this line: `const isValid = payload[key].length === 0 || regex.phoneNumber.test(payload[key]);` will return `false` until the 10 digits are complete regardless of whether its a correct phone number or not. Now once it does return `true`, this line `const [key] = Object.keys(payload);` no longer runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting proper json in `this.props.validationErrors` in `_validate` function then just use `Current Value (curr)` instead of `Accumulator (acc)` in that function like this:

```
if (this.props.validationErrors[curr] !== "") {
     return false;
}
```

Comment: @Daniel And if this does not work then it will be better if you will share code on expo snacks so that we can help you in better way.

Comment: I ended up replacing `reduce()` with `map()` and inside of it passed it your answer. It works, but I feel like its not the most elegant solution. So are you suggesting to remove the `Object.keys().reduce()` part altogether? I would like to check your answer because its close to what I did, but just need clarification.

Comment: @Daniel That two lines you just needed to change in your existing`reduce()` method. because you were using `accumulator (acc)` instead of `Current Value (curr)`. You can also implement this using simple `for loop` or `map`.

Comment: this seems to work on iOS, any idea why it still fails on Android? What is the difference?

Comment: There should not be any problem with android for this code. Check by putting logs in your functions.

Comment: I think Android likes to cache a lot, not sure, but it worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

You should do one of the followings:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log("there should be a phone number here: ", event.target.value);
  }
```

or

```
...
handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
...
```

Comment: followed your answer and I am still getting `undefined`.

Comment: I have edited the question further, I believe the problem is in the `_validate` function.

Comment: please take another look at the question. There is a bounty on it this time.